# configmap port forward doesn't work in kubernetes multicontainer pod

Tags: kubernetes

Below is  configMap file for the pod containing multiple container.
  Port number 80 is exposed to external world and it will then redirect to port 5000 of another container running in the pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mc3-nginx-conf
data:
  nginx.conf: |-
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        sendfile        on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        upstream webapp {
            server 127.0.0.1:5000;
        }

        server {
            listen 80;

            location / {
                proxy_pass         http://webapp;
                proxy_redirect     off;
            }
        }
    }


$kubectl apply -f confimap.yaml
```

The pod configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mc3
  labels:
    app: mc3
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webapp
    image: training/webapp
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: nginx-proxy-config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      subPath: nginx.conf
  volumes:
  - name: nginx-proxy-config
    configMap:
      name: mc3-nginx-conf
```

Step 3. Expose the Pod using the NodePort service:

```
$ kubectl expose pod mc3 --type=NodePort --port=80
service "mc3" exposed
```

Step 4. Identify port on the node that is forwarded to the Pod:

```
$ kubectl describe service mc3

Name:                     mc3
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=mc3
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=mc3
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       100.68.152.108
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32636/TCP
Endpoints:                100.96.2.3:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

But i am unable to perform curl

```
$ curl 100.96.2.3:80

$ curl http://100.96.2.3:80

$ curl http://100.96.2.3:32636
```

So,i want to know why this redirection doesn't work.

Source: https://www.mirantis.co.jp/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/

Its written on the page that we can access using url

http://myhost:

Now,what is myhost here ?
and ,i understood that port exposed is 32636

But ,i am not able to access from browser or curl /wget command.

Comment: On what plateform are you making your deployment, Is your nodeport exposed on the internet? Are you using a bastion to curl from inside a provider?

Comment: I am executing on google cloud shell .  Nodeport is not exposed to internet but to local environment outside pod.  You can refer the link where diagram is also shown . Single pod multiple container architecture ,where container port is forwarded.  So from the google cloud shell itself i am executing curl command and wget command .

Comment: Ok, so the 3rd form is the good one... Now do you have ipaliasing or not?

Comment: I actually tried you config map, pod and service and they work fine for me, You are probably using the wrong Ip address, the address you should be curling to is the Ip adress of one of your cluster nodes

Comment: You should add to your question, the outout of: `Kubectl get all`, maybe your pod isn't running yet.

Comment: Try adding port not to your security firewall rule

Comment: @Ezwig  kubectl get all
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

pod/mc3   2/2     Running   0          25h

pod/mc4   2/2     Running   0          6h22m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.39.240.1     <none>        443/TCP        25h 

service/mc3          NodePort    10.39.255.143   <none>        80:31434/TCP   25h

Comment: Looks like the port you should be using is 31434, you shoudl add the output to the body of your question, it is not visible in the comment, and it will help peoeple when trying to help you.

Comment: @Penguin Tech Could you please update the question as suggested by @Ezwig?
Have you tried with port 31434?

Comment: I have tried with port 31434 ,still it doesn't work. Also on one of my colleague tried and result is same.

Comment: 1. Have you checked your firewall rules? 2. Could you provide some logs? 3. When you run `curl -v` does the output is empty or you wait for it forever? Does it return any error?

Comment: kubectl get service mc3                                                                               
NAME   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
mc3    NodePort   10.59.242.245   <none>        80:31357/TCP   116m
XXXXX@cloudshell:~ (pubsub-quickstart-XXXXX)$ curl -v http://10.59.242.245:31357
* Rebuilt URL to: http://10.59.242.245:31357/
*   Trying 10.59.242.245...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.59.242.245 port 31357 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.59.242.245 port 31357: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7)

Comment: @PenguinTech Please add the requested info to the question itself. It is hardly visible for the rest of the community.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you're having trouble connecting with your application over the `NodePort`.

In the comments you posted:
`I am executing on google cloud shell`, so I assume you are running on GKE.

You also posted in comments:

```
XXXXX@cloudshell:~ (pubsub-quickstart-XXXXX)$ curl -v 10.59.242.245:31357 * Rebuilt URL to: 10.59.242.245:31357 * Trying 10.59.242.245... * TCP_NODELAY set * connect to 10.59.242.245 port 31357 failed: Connection timed out * Failed to connect to 10.59.242.245 port 31357: Connection timed out * Closing connection 0 curl: (7)`
```

So I see you are trying to `curl` private ip address of your cluster node from `cloudshell`
and that will not work.

It is impossible to connect to a node over private addresses from `cloudshell`
as these instances are in different networks (separated from each other).

To connect to your application from external network you need to use `EXTERNAL-IP`'s of your nodes which can be found running `kubectl get no -owide`

Second thing (very important) is to create a firewall rule to allow ingress traffic to this port e.g. using gcloud cli:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow tcp:[NODE_PORT]
```

More information on exposing application on GKE can be found in [GKE documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps).

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks @HelloWorld . Superb!! I got the result after adding firewall rule.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.